# Resize Cursor - Col/Row vs East-West/North-South

Tags: icons, cursor, resizing

I have a website with 2 panels. The user can resize these two panel using drag-n-drop.

I want to change the mouse cursor, when the mouse is hovering over the edge of these two panels, to a Resize-Cursor.

However, I've noticed that there are two types of cursor icons for resize (for both vertical and horizontal).

Cursors East-West (aka ew) and North-South (aka ns):

[image]
[image]

Cursors Col and Row:

[image]
[image]

What is the difference between these two pairs of icons, and when should I use each one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Microsoft Mouse and Pointers documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/uxguide/inter-mouse),

[image: A screenshot showing the different pointers used for Resizing and Splitting]

---

### Behaviours:

**Behaviour 1**

Dragging the edge increases the size of the two panels combined. The panels' size increases with some defined logic(usually the last panel size like End A or in a proportional way like End B).

[image: Behaviour 1: Dragging the edge increases the size of the two panels combined.]

**Behaviour 2**

Dragging a partition increases the size of the two panels combined.

[image: Behaviour 2: Dragging a partition increases the size of the two panels combined.]

**Behaviour 3**

Dragging a partition changes the sizes of the panels but the panels' combined size remains the same.

[image: Behaviour 3: Dragging a partition changes the sizes of the panels but the panels' combined size remains the same.]

Answer (score 0):

Both options are intuitive enough. I would choose first because it is simpler ("less visual noise"). Also second one is usually associated with spreadsheets, that's why the names are Col and Row.